# Что означает фраза "типун тебе на язык"?

Tags: этимология

Что означает фраза "типун тебе на язык"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типун - поврежденное или воспаленное место на языке, обычно - вкусовой сосочек, небольшой нарыв. Считалось, что он может вскочить если человека поймали на лжи или сказанной гадости. Хотя на самом деле исходно "типун" - патологический нарост на языке у некоторых птиц, вероятно вирусной этиологии, иногда приобретает масштабы эпизоотии (вернее сказать - "эпиптерии").

Вся фраза, таким образом, означает недовольство сказанным, шутливое пожелание более внимательно относиться к своим словам, не лгать, не кликушествовать и т.л.  - по ситуации.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то  тяпун.   Это топор, которым язык отрубали, на то в корне тяп и стоит чуть кривовато. 
Нечего болтать лишнее, пока язык не оттяпали. А про нарост это уже потом. Придумали те, кому язык не укоротили вовремя.

Comment: >Это топор, которым язык отрубали

А можно ссылку? Или какое-то подтверждение...

>Придумали те, кому язык не укоротили вовремя.

Сурово вы пишете... почти грубо.

Comment: >А можно ссылку? Или какое-то подтверждение...  
  
Вопрос не мне, но брошу свои пять копеек. В сети есть упоминания о топоре-*тяпуне* как "прародителе" *типуна*, я их видел, но уровень достоверности таких домыслов уж никак не годится для *подтверждения*. Нельзя же любое созвучие объяснять этимологическим родством.

Comment: Nikolja--- ссылку на топор? или тесак,ножик? Так те уже сказать ничего не могут, только ссылаются, вопрос, на кого? Шутка. Ссылка, дело не хитрое:  "на бога надейся, а сам не плошай". С прыщом говорить еще можно, без языка, нет. 
behemothus--интересно, а как вы оцениваете уровень достоверности, количеством  или качеством копирования цитат из Vасмера?В самом топоре тот же корень, звучит не по-узбекски, вполне по-русски. А еще и второй корень имеется. Это когда орут при выдохе на ударе. А еще в импортном названии топора междометие Ах..., полено пополам или  нет головушки. Не зря он еще и balta.

Comment: Отрезать язык - слышал, отрубить язык - не доводилось, да и звучит как то не по-русски.  
А типун "выскакивает" на языке, если "ляпнул" что-то неладное.  
А было бы интересно узнать Вашу версию этимологии слов топор и тесак.
А при ударе я иногда выдыхаю - "хух", что у парсов означает "слово". Может, один только я?  
А интересно, где кончается этимология и начинается вольная борьба?

Comment: Это называется  «слышал звон, да не знаю, где он». Или вы знакомы с технологией отрезания языка у человека, который ой как не хочет этого?
Или вы знакомы с примерами того, что на языке после «ляпнул что-то неладное»  что либо вообще «выскакивает»?  
Похоже, вы один только на фарси «хухом» и изъясняетесь, даже парсы давно на гуджарати говорят.

Comment: Поясню, приговоренные к казне «отрубанием головы» сами, самостоятельно голову на плаху клали. А уж язык и подавно, чтоб вместе с ним головы не лишиться.
Это тривиально и гораздо проще, чем сопротивляться, оно себе дороже. Да и раньше надо было думать, а не языком чесать.
Ах уж эти сказки и сказочники про прыщи  и ножики,  языки режущие.  Палач с ножом для отрезания языка — узкая специализация, смешно до колик.
.
Вот тут именно и кончается этимология и начинается вольная борьба с фантастами.

Comment: Что то в ларек ваш завезли...

Comment: Я думаю, оно в том ларьке никого и не переводилось. Обычно я не переношу разборки с одной темы в другую, но тут явное исключение. Если посмотреть по другим вопросам, ларек тот на спрос не жалуется.

>@behemothus, интересно, а как вы оцениваете уровень достоверности,   
  
Органолептически. Если мне смешно с ваших умозаключений, значит они недостоверны. А вы можете предложить другой метод? Хотя да, мне еще иногда глаза помогают. Если Вы в каком-то посте начинаете (непонятно на кой) уродовать имена и фамилии, то ничего кроме бреда такой коммент не содержит.

Comment: >Это называется «слышал звон, да не знаю, где он».    
    
Вставьте это себе в подпись.  
Как раз про "типун", который "тяпун". Неужели вы серьезно полагаете, что написанное неизвестно кем, неизвестно по какому поводу и неизвесно на каком основании нуждается еще в какой-то "оценке достоверности"? Я такие версии обычно даже не рассматриваю. А Вы разве не минусуете все то, что противоречит вашим версиям, неизвестно на какой помойке найденным? А то можно подумать, что вы лично, лежа на плахе, интересовались у палача, как называется его орудие производства.

Comment: Кто про ларек, а кто про помойку.
Кто о чем, в меру своей испорченности.

Comment: А чья-то испорченность безмерна. Поэтому он ищет вдохновение в чужих словах.